# how do i add up values in 2d arrays?

Tags: java, methods, multidimensional-array

So i want to create a program that will print true or false depending on the values of the array. If the values in the 2d array (row and column) each equal 15. so the values in the row equal 15 and the values in the column equal 15. My code so far:

```
public static boolean isAmazingArray(int[][] array) {
    int rowTemp = 0;
    int colTemp = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[0].length; col++) {
            rowTemp += array[row][0];
            colTemp += array[0][col];


        }
        if (rowTemp == 15 && colTemp == 15) {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Quick clarification: We are checking if the sum of each row and column is equal to 15?

Comment: What's not working? What efforts did you do to debug yourself?

Comment: yea, i am trying to check the sum of every row and every column and see if it is equal to 15.

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc I'm still not sure how to debug programs that well, need some help on that

Comment: Well, first of all, what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Simple for iteration can do this. Notably, however, this requires that the array is non-jagged (array[i].length == array[0].length for all i in range). If this isn't the case it could still be valid, but the problem becomes a bit more interesting.... fixing...

```
public static boolean isAmazingArray(int[][] array) {
    final int VALID_VAL = 15;
    //Check Rows - handle jagged rows without issue
    for (int[] row : array) {
        int a = 0;
        for(int i : row) {a += i;}
        if(a != VALID_VAL) return false; //Found a bad row
    }

    //Check Cols - handle jagged-ness by finding max length row first.
    int maxRowLength = 0;
    for(int[] i : array){
        maxRowLength = Math.max(maxRowLength, i.length);
    }
    //Init array to hold running sum for each column
    int[] colSums = new int[maxRowLength];
    for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++){
           //Add value to its corresponding column sum
           colSums[c] += array[r][c];
        }
    }

    for(int i : colSums){
        //Found bad column
        if(i != VALID_VAL) return false;
    }

    //No invalid rows/cols found
    return true;
}
```

Comment: how come under the part where it is checking the columns, in the for loop it says int r = 0 and then i < array.length? two different variables?